# java load values from database into comboBox

Tags: java

Hi my aim is to load combobox with vaules from a database the code below works fine with one issue i get two of the first item so what must i do to prevent this

```
public void loadCombos() {
    try {
        try {
            String cs = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/booksalvation6";
            String user = "root";
            String password = "letmein";
            jComboBox2.removeAllItems();// make sure old data gone
            PreparedStatement pstpost;
            ResultSet rspost;
            conCombos = DriverManager.getConnection(cs, user, password);

            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {

                String querypost = "select * from post "
                        + "WHERE postage_id =" + i;

                // load postage selections
                pstpost = conCombos.prepareStatement(querypost);
                rspost = pstpost.executeQuery();

                while (rspost.next()) {
                    String Mypost = rspost.getString(6);
                    jComboBox2.addItem(Mypost);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BasicFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        conCombos.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BasicFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `PreparedStatement` but not in proper way.

Since you are looking only for one column to fetch all the column values which have postage_id between 1 to 10.

You can achieve it in single query:

```
select unique(combo_value_column_name) from post 
                                       where postage_id>=? and postage_id<=?
```

set the parameter via calling [`PreparedStatement#setInt(index,value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt%28int,%20int%29) set it 1 and 10.

Just fetch *single column* and only *unique values*.

It's better explained under *Java Tutorial* on [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

---

Instead of calling `JComboBox#addItem()` first prepare the whole list then finally set it once.

[Read more...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Final Note: Follow Java Naming Convention.